# Find and remove outdated AMIs in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I need to remove a list of outdated Ami's in AWS. But first I require to verifying are there any place still using those Ami's. Is there an efficient way to find it out.

Comment: you get all the instances and check what AMI they are using. Good luck!

Comment: Please Edit your question to tell us what you mean by "outdated AMIs". Also, what do you mean by "still using those AMIs"? The fact that an Amazon EC2 instance has been launched from an AMI should not impact your ability to delete an AMI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to define "Outdated AMIs", it can be the creation date or something else. But here is the script that will list Instance ID along with AMI details that used by particular instance in particular region. By default it will look into default region.

```sh
#Get list of EC2 instance
echo "Getting EC2"
EC2_LIST=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{InstanceId:InstanceId}' --output text | tr '\n' ' ')
#Get list of AMI used by ec2
echo "Getting AMI"
LIST_AMI_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ImageId:ImageId,InstanceId:InstanceId}' --output text | tr '\n' ' ')

EC2_LIST_ARRAY=($EC2_LIST)
LIST_AMI_ID_ARRAY=($LIST_AMI_ID)

for index in ${!LIST_AMI_ID_ARRAY[*]}; do

echo "Get details for AMI ${LIST_AMI_ID_ARRAY[$index]}"
#Get details of AMI
AMI_DETAILS=$(aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ${LIST_AMI_ID_ARRAY[$index]} --query 'Images[].{CreationDate:CreationDate,Tags:Tags[]}')
echo "Instance having ID ${EC2_LIST_ARRAY[$index]} using  AMI ID ${LIST_AMI_ID_ARRAY[$index]}  Details: $AMI_DETAILS"
done
```

output

```sh
Get details for AMI ami-0219162cf838b3455
Instance having ID i-0ceb0dfa197fd7455 using  AMI ID ami-0219162cf838b3455  Details: [
    {
        "CreationDate": "2019-10-22T05:17:46.000Z",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Key": "Base_AMI_Name",
                "Value": "ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20191021"
            },
            {
                "Key": "OS_Version",
                "Value": "Ubuntu"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Release",
                "Value": "Latest"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "postgres"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Scope",
                "Value": "database"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

[aws-cli-cheatsheet](https://github.com/Adiii717/aws-cli-cheatsheet/blob/master/ec2/README.MD#query-ami-being-used-by-instance-and-describe-ami-details)

Comment: Error from variable: LIST_AMI_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ImageId:ImageId,InstanceId:InstanceId}' --output text | tr '\n' ' ').
An error occurred (InvalidAMIID.Malformed) when calling the DescribeImages operation: Invalid id: (expecting "ami-...")

The InstanceId:InstanceId is causing it, please check.

Comment: working for me `LIST_AMI_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ImageId:ImageId,InstanceId:InstanceId}' --output text --profile my-profile --region us-west-2 | tr '\n' ' ')`, you might missing region, access or older cli version?

Comment: I have modified it to next to get it work: `LIST_AMI_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region my-region --profile my-profile --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ImageId:ImageId}' --output text | tr '\n' ' ')`.
Issue is that further code doesn't expect Instance ID followed by AMI ID. With `{ImageId:ImageId,InstanceId:InstanceId}` it doesn't work. 
With `{ImageId:ImageId}` only, it works.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I built a small tool for this purpose as well -- a bit of JavaScript wrapped around AWS API calls.

This basically tries to find all the AMIs in use in your account and looks at both AMIs by their age and also the newly introduced deprecated flag:

- https://github.com/geoffreywiseman/oldamis
- https://www.codiform.com/blog/oldamis/

It's pretty simplistic currently, but I'm willing to entertain feature requests. ;)